# .net webservice, help with method parameters

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services

When writing  a .net  webservice, can I use a existing xsd to be my parameters for my web service method. I want to point to the xsd and the web method will be created for me, instead of coding it.
I am using vs 2005, framework 2.0.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163800.aspx for more info on contract first development in .net web services.

The bottom line is it is possible but often requires more work and care than code first...

Answer (score 0):

you can use xsd.exe to generate a class file from your xsd schema
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.80).aspx